# Training data retrieval

Tags: engines, evaluation, database, chess-ai

I am currently developing a chess engine which uses minimax algorithm to evaluate chess positions. In addition to this I want to improve my current static evaluation with reinforcement learning. I have connected my chess engine to postgres database. In this database I store previously played chess positions via board hash and counters of white victories, black victories and stalemates resulting from that position during training. Currently my training dataset is small so I am able to retrieve all of my data from database and store it in hashmap but I presume that at some point my training data will get large enough that I will be unable to store all of it in memory. I cannot retrieve data individually as that would introduce significant overhead. I need to use some sort of caching system. How would you retrieve this data in batches?